# Firebase restoring initial values in textfields after changing text value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift2

I am practicing iOS (Swift) with Firebase. the first viewcontroller retrieves all the records from firebase db and populate the tableView from an array. when the user selects an item from that tableview a new viewcontroller pops up segueing the object from the listView viewcontroller to the detail viewcontroller. data is populated to the fields successfully!

however when i try to update any of the textfield, the moment i switch to another textfield the initial value is restored in the edited textfield.

I have tried to removeAllObservers... but nothing worked. i even removed "import Firebase" and all associated objects and still it restores the initial value.

am i missing any concept here?

this is the code from the ListViewController:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated);

    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating();

    self.observeIngrdUpdates = ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.ingredients.removeAll();

        for child in snapshot.children {
            var nutrition:String = "";
            var type:Int = 0;
            var desc:String = "";
            var img:String = "";
            var name:String = "";
            var price:Double = 0.0;

            if let _name = child.value["IngredientName"] as? String {
                name = _name;
            }

            if let _nutrition = child.value["NutritionFacts"] as? String {
                nutrition = _nutrition;
            }

            if let _type = child.value["IngredientType"] as? Int {
                type = _type;
            }

            if let _desc = child.value["UnitDescription"] as? String {
                desc = _desc;
            }

            if let _img = child.value["IngredientImage"] as? String {
                img = _img;
            }

            if let _price = child.value["IngredientPrice"] as? Double {
                price = _price;
            }

            let ingredient = Ingredient(name: name, type: type, image: img, unitDesc: desc, nutritionFacts: nutrition, price: price);
            ingredient.key = child.key;

            self.ingredients.append(ingredient);

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData();
    })
}
```

and the PrepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EditIngredientVC;
    if segue.identifier?.compare(SEGUE_EDIT_INGREDIENTS) == .OrderedSame {
        destinationVC.ingredient = ingredients[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row];
        destinationVC.controllerTitle = "Edit";
    } else if segue.identifier?.compare(SEGUE_ADD_INGREDIENT) == .OrderedSame {
        destinationVC.controllerTitle = "New";
    }
}
```

this is the code for populating the fields in DetailViewController:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    lblControllerTitle.text = controllerTitle;
    if controllerTitle?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("NEW") == .OrderedSame {
        self.segVegFru.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

    } else {

        if ingredient != nil {
            self.txtIngredientName.text = ingredient!.name;
            self.txtUnitDesc.text = ingredient!.unitDesc;
            self.segVegFru.selectedSegmentIndex = ingredient!.typeInt;
            self.txtNutritionFacts.text = ingredient!.nutritionFacts;
            self.txtPrice.text = "\(ingredient!.price)";
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you are putting your textField populating code, in viewDidLayoutSubviews() method. 
This method will be triggered every time the layout of a views changes in viewcontroller.

Move it to viewDidLoad() and it should be fine.

The reason that it's being reverted to the previous value is because. You are populating the textField.text from the "ingredient" object. The ingredient will have the same value retained that you passed from previous view controller. Until you mutate it at some point.

And by the way Firebase is very cool I like it too :)

Comment: Thanks alot, i didnt know that about viewDidLayoutSubviews method. how come it runs even if i dont change the views sizes or is it that values is also considered to trigger the method?

Comment: Many view changes happen when you activate a textField. I don't know specifically which ones but it affects multiple views layout. The cursor in the textField, keyboard etc.